# How to access a binary resource file from a location in the application package in UWP (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

Under Windows 8.1 (Silverlight), my phone oriented C# application was using the following code to access a binary file from my application package:

```
BinaryWriter fileWriter = new BinaryWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myWorkingStreamIOfile.pcm", FileMode.Create, fileStorage));

var uri = new Uri("assets/ myFileInMyProjectAssets.pcm", UriKind.Relative);
var res = App.GetResourceStream(uri);
long fileLength = res.Stream.Length;
BinaryReader fileReader = new BinaryReader(res.Stream);
var buffer = new byte[1024];
int readCount = 0;
while (readCount < fileLength)
{
    int read = fileReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    readCount += read;
    fileWriter.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

But “GetResourceStream” is not available anymore under UWP. Any help on how the above can be achieve under Window 10 would be very welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is how to open the files. In the example below I open the file from /Assets folder inside the application package (remember to set file to `Build Action` as `Content` and `Copy to output directory`) and then I copy the binary content to a file in the local app data folder, in the same way as in your code.

Also I omitted the checks, but `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()` will throw an exception if the file is not found.

```
// Create or overwrite file target file in local app data folder
var fileToWrite = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("myWorkingStreamIOfile.pcm", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
// Open file in application package
var fileToRead = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/myFileInMyProjectAssets.pcm", UriKind.Absolute));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
using (BinaryWriter fileWriter = new BinaryWriter(await fileToWrite.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()))
{
    using (BinaryReader fileReader = new BinaryReader(await fileToRead.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
    {
        long readCount = 0;
        while (readCount < fileReader.BaseStream.Length)
        {
            int read = fileReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            readCount += read;
            fileWriter.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a good resource on the URI format for universal apps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx